# Uncaught TypeError: PouchDB is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, pouchdb

I'm struggling to understand this error: ***Uncaught TypeError: PouchDB is not a constructor***

The code is as follows:

```
var PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
var db = new PouchDB("scr");
```

I've read about how it may be related to types and that adding:

```
 "@types/node": "^10.12.0",
 "@types/pouchdb": "^6.3.2",
```

to my package.json should help, but it isn't. I've tested on another simple .js file and works, but on my main app it isn't. Still, I don't understand why it wouldn't work. The pouch documentation is quite clear https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_document.

I should mention I'm running this on the context of an electron app, not in the browser.

I'm baffled at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: this is probably electron specific, it works fine in vanilla node.js

Comment: There's a number of possible fixes detailed at https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6692

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6614)

To use PouchDB with Typescript:

**Install PouchDB**

1. npm install pouchdb-browser
2. npm install --save-dev @types/pouchdb-browser

**Add to your source file**

1. At the top in your "imports" section

   const PouchDB = require('pouchdb-browser');

   const pouchDB = PouchDB.default.defaults();
2. To instantiate the database

   const db = new pouchDB('MyDB');

The rest is all [here](https://pouchdb.com/api.html).

Answer (score 4):

For without constructor use .default

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb').default;
```

Answer (score 1):

change :
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');

to :
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming because the compiler is not able to get the pouch DB constructor from the package.

**To use pouch DB as a function &  without the constructor:-**

- Import pouch DB as :- `const PouchDB = require('pouchdb').default;` in your TS file.
- Then run: `npm i --save-dev @types/node` command to install the type support for node from the npm registry.
- Then in **tsconfig.app.json** file add  `"types": ["node"]` in compiler  object. This step is used to support node types example 'require'.
- To instantiate the database add this in your TS file `const db = PouchDB('MyDB');`
- Then serve the project

**To use pouch DB  with the constructor:-**

- Import pouch DB as:- `import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'` in your TS file.
- To instantiate the database add this to your TS file `const db = new PouchDB('MyDb');`
- Then serve the project.